# iOS Custom Keyboard Default code run takes over 40 MB in memory causing app crash

Tags: swift, memory, crash, keyboard

I’m making a custom keyboard extension in Swift 4.2 with Xcode10.

I'm new to create an extension in Xcode 10.

I created a single View application as a Containing App and added a target custom Keyboard extension.

And then as a trial, did run the default code WITHOUT any modification on iPhone 7 Simulator.

But this Xcode templated default code (which renders only the "next keyboard" UIButton) failed to run.

Error log says

[App Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOut.png)

And after the first run failure, I did try the same run once more.
This time, it seems to be run normally in Simulator except memory usage.
The default code run memory exceeds over 40 MB. (WITHOUT ANY MODIFICATION both in the Containing app and keyboard extension ViewController!!)

[Default Code iPhone 7 Simulator Run on iMessageApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alum1.png)

Could anyone have an opinion why memory usage in the default code run is so large?

Comment: I think I found a reason why the first problem (app crash) occurs. It may be due to "Vacant" containing app.
This [link](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/) tells me that Apple doesn't allow containing app to be a skeleton app. The containing app must have at least one functionality, e.g., a TextView on the main screen in its storyboard.